# UserVoice widget close button event override

Tags: javascript, dom-events, uservoice

I want to be able to modify or add to the onclick of the a href tag for a UserVoice widget.

This code is generated for me.

```
<a title="Close Dialog" id="uservoice-dialog-close" onclick="UserVoice.Dialog.close(); return false;" href="#close"><span style="display: none;">Close Dialog</span></a>
```

I want to call what is there but add my own method when clicking close.  I do not or do not want to modify the source that generates this code but rather add to it upon document ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery to the rescue.

This works:

```
$("#uservoice-dialog-close").live("click", function() {
    DoFunction();
});
```

I was trying:

```
$("#uservoice-dialog-close").bind("click", function() {
    DoFunction();
});
```